# SQL Server Two FileTables visible in Share

Tags: sql-server

I'm wondering how I have to set up my database with filetables, filgroups and so on.

My goal is to see at least two different folders in my share

Don't know the real relations between FileGroup, File and FileTable so maybe this is the main issue why I don't get it work... maybe someone can give me a useful hint!

```
ALTER DATABASE KIT_TEST
ADD FILEGROUP KIT_TEST2 CONTAINS FILESTREAM;


ALTER DATABASE KIT_TEST  
SET FILESTREAM ( NON_TRANSACTED_ACCESS = FULL, DIRECTORY_NAME = N'KIT_TEST1');


ALTER DATABASE KIT_TEST
ADD FILE
(
    NAME = File1,
    FILENAME = 'C:\test\KIT_TEST'
) TO FILEGROUP KIT_TEST2;


CREATE TABLE dbo.FileTable1 AS FileTable
WITH (
FileTable_Directory = 'PRIVATE[![enter image description here][1]][1]_FILES',
FileTable_Collate_Filename = database_default);
```

Thx!

Comment: This is SQL Server, correct? Can you tag your database?

Comment: You mentioned you couldn't get it to work. Did you get an error? If so, what error? Have you [enabled the prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/enable-the-prerequisites-for-filetable)? To see 2 more folders in the file table share, you need to insert 2 more folder rows into the file table. That can be done with INSERT statements or directly in the file table share using Windows explorer.